# cant get 'li' item to center in div

Tags: html, css

I cant get this list to center properly in a containing div. It's leaving a margin on the left hand side and i have tried a few things but can't seem to change it. i am only new to css so still in the process of learning. appreciate the help in advance

Here is a jsfiddle for a better example: http://jsfiddle.net/aSmfy/

html

```
<div id="navContainer">
                        <ul>

                              <li><a href="add_contact.php">Add Contact</a></li>
                              <li><a href="list-contacts.php">List Contact</a></li>    

                        </ul>
                </div>
```

CSS

```
#navContainer {
    width: 192px;}

#navContainer ul{
    width: 192px;
    }

#navContainer li{
    list-style-type:none;
    border-top:thin solid white;
    border-bottom:thin solid white;}
```

Comment: remove padding from `ul`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a padding of 0 on your `ul` element:

```
#navContainer ul{
    width: 190px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aSmfy/1/

Answer (score 1):

add:

```
margin:0;
padding:0;
```

to #navContainer ul

and :

```
 text-align:center;
```

to #navContainer li

and it should center

Answer (score 0):

**Solution one** :

```
#navContainer {
width: 192px;
left: -20%;
position: relative;
}
```

check this  [jSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JZm5E/)

**Solution Two:**

```
#navContainer li{
        list-style-type:none;
    border-top:thin solid white;
    border-bottom:thin solid white;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        text-align:center;
}
```

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uy5zm/)